# python3: convert string to type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of classes `A`, `B`, `C` in a "front end" package `p1`. They all inherit from `p1.X`.

I have another set of classes `A`, `B`, `C` in a "back end" package `p2`. They all inherit from `p2.Y`.

In `p1.X`, I set one backend, so that `p1.A` uses `p2.A` as backend, `p1.B` uses `p2.B`, etc. This mapping is done based on the class name in an inherited method.

Now, I suceed to have, for example, `backend = "p2.A"` (string), but when I try to eval this, python doesn't knows about `p2`, even if this is imported earlier.

What did I do wrong? Should I import inside the eval? Should like spaghetti code... Do you have a better idea?

Thanks.

P.S.: I currently have something like this in the "parent" `p1.X` class, which is awful, but good to clarify what I want:

```
def getBackendClass(self):
    myClass = ... # (class without package name)
    if myClass == "A":
           return p2.A
    elif myClass == "B":
           return p2.B
    ...
```

Comment: Why not have a mapping `{classname: class}`, then use `getattr` to access the method?

Comment: Thanks Jon, but my intention is to avoid hard coding this. With your example, I should have `{p1.A: p2.A, p2.B: p2.B, ...}` (I have A, B, ... equal more or less 30 different classes). The mapping is systematic (I used a vim script to write it...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I've made a mix of all your answers, leading the following code in the front end:

```
import backend

class Parent:
    @property
    def backend_class(self):
        return getattr(backend, self.__class__.__name__)

class A(Parent):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = A()
    backendInstance = instance.backend_class()
```

Comment about cython: the backend must be imported, not cimported, even if "pure cython" `cdef` classes/`cpdef` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Little hacky solution, but should work, and is not hardcoded.

p2.py:

```
class Y(object):
    @classmethod
    def fromString(cls, s):
        cls_name = s.split(".")[1]
        for c in cls.__subclasses__():
            if c.__name__() == cls_name:
                return c()
        raise ValueError("%s not found in subclasses" % s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean something like this? Whenever the `backend_class` attribute is fetched it will call it's `__get__` method and return the result of that call. The `BackendClassFetcher` is known as a non-data descriptor.

**package1/m1.py**

```
from . import p2

class BackendClassFetcher:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return getattr(p2, objtype.__name__)

class Parent:
    backend_class = BackendClassFetcher()    
class A(Parent): pass
class B(Parent): pass
class C(Parent): pass

for cls in [A,B,C]:
    obj = cls()
    print(cls, cls.backend_class, obj.backend_class)
```

**package1/m2.py**

```
class Parent: pass
class A(Parent): pass
class B(Parent): pass
class C(Parent): pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import_module`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)

sample:

```
from importlib import import_module

path = "p2.A"
cls_name = path.split('.')[-1]
module_path = ".".join(path.split('.')[:-1])

module = import_module(module_path)
cls = getattr(module, cls_name)
```

Good luck.